# this and stage in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having a little confusion when distinguishing this in an as3 file

lets say I have a main stage linked to a Main.as

then whats the differenence between

> this.addChild() 
> stage.addChild()

also what type of object is "this"

lets say I create a class and pass in an instance of "this" so i can refer to stage from inside the MC

> var mc:Derp = new Derp(this)

inside derp what is this? Is it of type generic object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside members of a class, `this` refers to the current instance that the member function was called on (so it's always of the same type as the class). For example, if you had a class Twang with a member function `func`:

```
var twang1:Twang = new Twang();
twang1.func();        // Inside func(), "this" will refer to twang1
```

Flash first creates the stage (of type [`Stage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html)) onto which everything else must be placed (either directly or indirectly). Then, it instantiates an instance of your document class, and places that on the stage as a child. So, `this` in your code can never refer to the stage, since you didn't write the `Stage` class.

Because the display tree is hierarchical in Flash, when you add something to a child object which is already on the stage (at least indirectly) it will appear on screen. So the difference between `this.addChild()` and `stage.addChild()` is which container the object will end up being inserted into.

When passing `this` to another object's constructor, it will be of the type of the class in which the method (which uses `this`) is defined; so in this case, it will be the type of the document class.

Instead of passing display object containers to other objects in order for them to add children to it, you can have you classes inherit from Sprite (or some other `DisplayObjectContainer`) and add children to *themselves*. Then, you can add the object you created (which will contain subobjects) to yourself (the document class instance), which is on the stage. This gives much better encapsulation, too.

Note also that if you want to add children to the stage directly you don't need to pass the stage around to those objects; they already have a `stage` property just for this purpose. The only tricky thing about that property is that it is null until the object is actually added to the stage; so, you need an event listener:

```
public class Car : Sprite {
    public Car() {
        this.addChild(new Wheel());    // Add to self

        this.addEventListener(event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, populateStage);
    }

    private function populateStage():void {
        stage.addChild(new RandomThingToAddToStage());
    }
}
```

Finally, note that you don't need to specify `this` in most cases. The following two lines are equivalent (within a method of a class):

```
addChild(foo);
this.addChild(foo);
```

Comment: @Saad: Yes? (I wrote this answer while sleep deprived BTW, so some parts likely aren't too clear)

Comment: @Cameron
ok let me get this straight:

at first we have

main >> stage (implicit)

then if we go

foo = new Foo()
adChild(foo);

we have 

main >> stage >> foo

and inside foo I have

foobar = new FooBar()
addChild(foobar);

we we have
main >> stage >> foo >> foobar

but what if I wanted to add foobar under the stage, basically our main.as but from inside foobar (dont I need to pass an instance of this into foo call it x, then go: x.addChild(foobar) ?

Comment: @Saad: Almost (the usual term for main is the "document class", BTW). We start with main >> stage as you say (taking ">>" to mean "contained by" or "on"). Then, if `addChild(foo)` is done in main, we get foo >> main >> stage. With foobar you get foobar >> foo >> main >> stage. If you want to add foobar to main instead, then you need to pass the instance to foo for it to use, yes. If you want foobar on the stage directly, you can say stage.addChild(foobar) inside foo (which avoids having to pass stage) -- but only once foo is actually on the stage itself (otherwise its stage property is null).

Comment: @Cameron
wait if its a hierarchy shouldn't main be on top of everything then as we add elements to ie like the stage or foo we are adding a branch. atm I'm picturing a tree where main is on top then an edge to main and main (document class) has a child called foo so an edge to foo.

but what you're writing is completely reverse how can a child of the root be on top?

Comment: @Saad: The stage is at the top of the hierarchy. Directly underneath is main, with a child foo. When you want foobar to appear, you have the option of where to insert it into the tree: you can add it as a child to the stage directly (via the stage property of foo once foo is on the stage, or by passing the stage explicitly); as a child to foo (easiest and most encapsulated); or as a child to the document class (main), which requires passing a reference of main down into foo where foobar is being created

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of a document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            this.addChild(new Sprite());

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        }// end function

        public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            stage.addChild(new Sprite());

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Using the example above, the `this` keyword refers to the current instance, in this(no pun intended) case that would be the `Main` display object. When you call `addChild()` method on this, you are calling the `addChild()` method on the `Main` display object. At this point, when you add the new `Sprite` instance, you add it to `Main` display object or in other words `this` display object.

`stage` on the other hand is a public property of `Main` that stores a reference to the stage. When you add a new instance of `Sprite` using the stage reference's `addChild()` method, you add that instance to the stage not the `Main` display object.

To put it simply `Main` is a child display object of the stage. So when you do `stage.addChild(new Sprite())`, stage now has two child objects, the new `Sprite` instance and `Main`. However when you do `this.addChild(new Sprite())` from within the `Main` class, you are refering to `Main`. So now the stage has a child display object `Main`, and `Main` has the new instance of `Sprite` as a child display object.

Comment: do main and stage share the same cartesian coordinates? stage.MC.x == Main.Mc.x

Comment: No, at least I don't think so, thats really another question. Did you get the difference between `this` and `stage` from my answer?

Comment: +1, this really emphasizes the difference between the stage and the document class with a good explanation of the hierarchy

Comment: Thanks, but after reading your answer, yours is the better of the two so I up voted it.